# Passing data into flask using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

i am trying to pass some data from html to python using ajax using post request. But the arguments for request are empty.

A simple endpoint, i am trying to print all the arguments that come in the form of request.

```
@app.route("/enter", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def enter_data():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        print("post")
        print(request.args)
        return render_template('index.html')
```

debug output

```
post

ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2016 00:40:12] "POST /enter HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

the ajax function is as below

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var user = $('#userinput').val();
        console.log(user);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/enter',
            data: JSON.stringify( {'user': $('#userinput').val()} ),
            type: 'POST',
            success: on_request_success,
            error: on_request_error,
            })
        });
    });
```

the value gets printed in js console. But its not present on python side.

html code

```
<body>
        <h3>The Chef Bucket</h3>
        Enter food you like to order.
        <input type="text" name="user_data" id="userinput" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button">

        <div id="userinputdata"> 
            {% if not entered %}
                <h4></h4>
            {% else %}
                <h4>{{ entered }}</h4>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: on_request_success function is where?

Comment: It does not print anything, because you have no args in `POST /enter`. What does it print if you do `POST /enter?foo=bar` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<form>` tag in your html code, so your `$('form').serialize()` doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<form>` tag in your html code. Therefore your `data` attribute of the ajax is request is empty. Either put your `<div>` in a `<form>` environment in the html or set your `data` attribute in the ajax request by hand:

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var user = $('#userinput').val();
        console.log(user);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/enter',
            data: JSON.stringify( {'user': $('#userinput').val()} ),
            type: 'POST',
            success: on_request_success,
            error: on_request_error,
            })
        });
    });
```

Note that the `data` attribute is here sent as an json object which you have to deserialize on the server side. If you want to keep it simple, just define it as a dictinary.